# NSDateFormatter always returning nil.

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am trying to convert a date time string from Django Rest Framework such as this:
"2014-10-28T18:14:32.457" into a Swift string. I am running the following code in a playground and always get the error:

*fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

```
import Foundation

var mydate =  "2014-10-28T18:14:32.457"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
var parsedDateTimeString = formatter.dateFromString(mydate)
formatter.stringFromDate(parsedDateTimeString!)
```

I think its because dateFromString is always returning nil. But I cant figure out why its returning nil. Im pretty sure i have the dateFormat correct. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're setting `dateFormat`, then you shouldn't set `timeStyle` or `dateStyle` (they'll override the format you set). You also might want to think about using optional binding instead of forced unwrapping to make your code a little safer:

```
var mydate = "2014-10-28T18:14:32.457"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
if let parsedDateTimeString = formatter.dateFromString(mydate) {
    formatter.stringFromDate(parsedDateTimeString)
} else {
    println("Could not parse date")
}
```

Running that in a Playground and looking at the `stringFromDate` line results in:

> 2014-10-28T18:14:32.457